# ??? Error using ==> set uicontrol handle passed to 'CurrentAxes' property - valid axes handle required

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

can help me to solve my problem. i'm create image processing algorithm with matlab, but found error:

```
??? Error using ==> set
uicontrol handle passed to 'CurrentAxes' property - valid axes handle required
```

this the code:

```
set(iniw.figure1,'CurrentAxes',iniw.Cover_Image);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the naming of your variables, you are trying to set the `CurrentAxes` of the figure to... an image. An `axes` is a container which *contains* the image object. You will need to first get the `axes` which contains the image and set *that* as the `CurrentAxes`. You can determine this using `ancestor`.

```
 set(iniw.figure1, 'CurrentAxes', ancestor(iniw.Cover_Image, 'axes'))
```